# Hook to run after removing a user

Tags: wordpress, multisite

I have a function where I duplicate a user to all subsite when they registered.

I achieved that by doing this:

```
function sync_user( $user_id )
{
    $list_ids = get_sites();
    $current_site = get_current_site();

    $info = get_userdata($user_id);



    foreach( $list_ids as $list )
    {

        if ( $list->blog_id != $current_site->id )
        {
            add_user_to_blog($list->id, $info->ID, 'subscriber');
        }

    }

    // quick fix for: above somehow doesn't add to main site. add to main site here.
    add_user_to_blog(1, $info->ID, 'subscriber');

}
```

Now, I want to "unsyc" the user when I removed the user from the site. I tried to hook it by using 'remove_user_from_blog', but it caused infinite loop.

Where can I hook the following code so that I can remove all those users that I added previously using above code?

```
function unsync_user( $user_id )
{
    $list_ids = get_sites();

    foreach( $list_ids as $list )
    {
        remove_user_from_blog( $user_id, $list->ID );
    }
}
```

edited the title for clarity

Answer (score 0):

AbdulRahman was correct about that. When user click 'remove' from the user list, the action not fire 'delete_user' or 'deleted_user' hook. I tested it.

I think it is tricky. So, here is how to add custom removed_user action. Add these lines below into your plugin.

```
add_action('remove_user_from_blog', function($user_id, $blog_id) {
    // checking current action
    // refer: wp-admin/users.php:99
    $wp_list_table = _get_list_table( 'WP_Users_List_Table' );

    if( $wp_list_table->current_action() != 'doremove' ) {
        return; // only proceed for specific user list action
    }

    $fire_removed_user_hook = null; // closure reference

    $fire_removed_user_hook = function() use ($user_id, $blog_id, &$fire_removed_user_hook) {
        do_action( 'removed_user', $user_id, $blog_id );

        // remove the hook back
        remove_action('switch_blog', $fire_removed_user_hook);
    };

    // restore_current_blog called at the last line in the remove_user_from_blog function
    // so action switch_blog fired
    add_action('switch_blog', $fire_removed_user_hook);
}, 10, 2);


add_action('removed_user', function($user_id, $blog_id) {
 // the user removed from be blog at this point
}, 10, 2);
```

Answer (score -1):

The hook "deleted_user" runs after a user is deleted ("delete_user" runs before the deletion occurs):

https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/deleted_user

Comment: Unfortunately, no. Removing and delete user is two different thing. I've tried Deleted user hook, but it doesn't get triggered when i remove the user from WP-Admin > Users screen